# Div and a Table side by side?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

So I have 2 Div's one with a form and one with a table. the problem is that the table div is coming below the form div. I tried using float right, and overflow css attributes. but still no success.
CSS styling of my table: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWQhL/1/)

[Full webpage here](http://designcubicle.cu.cc/webapp/index2.html)

HTML:

```
<div id="existing_ledgers">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Matman</td>
        <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>The</td>
        <td>Tick</td>
        <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: JSFiddles are good but please include your code in the question.

Comment: Needs some tweaking with the positioning, but `display: inline-block;` and `float: left` on both elements works fine.

Comment: that fiddle only has the div with the table, and the one with the form where is it? also that dive has the id "existing_ledgers" but there's no CSS for that ID at all xD

Comment: Please create a fiddle with your code and display it here. Makes it easier for us.

Comment: you'all can checkout the form on the webpage link given!

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in a parent div, give the parent div `display:inline-block`

Then give `float` right/left to your child divs

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bXupP/)

```
#registration-form {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;        
}
#existing_ledgers {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css    in your web page

```
 .DA_custom_form {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 auto 5em;
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;


      }

    #el {
        float: right;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 600px;
    }
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/izCyidk.jpg...works but I need the divs in center.50% form and 50% table

Comment: ok and add this 
div#ledger-form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 83.667em;
}

Answer (score 0):

using float left and defined widths of the containers: they have to fit into the container, both being 50% wide will solve the problem.
 here you have a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qLGJt/

```
#one, #existing_ledgers{float:left; width:50%; }
```